# What is a Distributed Software Progam? Wrt to GIT as an example

Tags: git

I am new to GIT and have been trying to understand the fundamentals that it has been based on. That took me to the concept of a Distributed Program.

To get a layman understanding I will try and keep the query simple keeping the following in context - A web based Distributed Porgram e.g GIT(My understanding is that GIT is a Distribute Program, kindly correct if otherwise with an appropriate example)

My basic understanding of a Distributed Program  is - that is has has minimum two nodes, REMOTE and LOCAL. Each node has the same parent copy as the base. Incase of GIT the copy is of CODE.

The LOCAL copy is what I have on my computer and REMOTE is somewhere else on the web on another computer. My queries are based on this understanding:

1. If I upload a program code for the first time, it becomes the ORIGINAL copy, right? Does this code upload on the GIT repository, which is called the central repository and is on the web? Or is it only the meta data of the CODE and its ORIGIN(in this case my LOCAL node) which is stored.
2. If someone in the web pulls this ORIGINAL copy they will create a REMOTE copy, right? For that does the ORIGINAL computer need to be connected to the internet at that time? I am talking a case for the first copy.
3. If the answer to (2) is yes, which means the central repository is only storing METADATA OF EACH NODE and the DIFF of the changes to the SOURCE for each VERSION change, correct?
4. And if 3 is an yes, then it means the CENTRAL REPOSITORY needs to be online always, just like any other server.

Kindly share your insights and help correct the above understanding.

Thanks,
Anand

Comment: Git is a very specific *example of* a distributed program. For more on distributed computing in general, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_computing. In the case of Git specifically, a key concept is that *there is no central repository.*

Answer (score 0):

Answers to your questions:

1. A full copy of the repository is uploaded. (one exception are hooks, that remain local)
2. Yes, you need to be connected somehow (it may be internet, intranet or just a removable device)
3. No. Central repository holds a full copy of the repository
4. No, I does not have to be always online. It is only required when you want to push/pull. Even though is it pretty common to have the central repository 100% online.

Comment: for answer for 2. What it means is that the user pulling needs to be connected and so does the centrail repository. But the one who is the CREATOR of the repository has uploaded the CODE BASE for the first time, does need to be online. And the reason is since the Central repository already has a full copy. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

git is a distributed source control management tool. In order to understand what distributed in this context means it is helpful to compare it with a non-distributed one, eg. subversion.

In subversion there is a central repository which is authoritative. If you check out the repository you only get a working copy (eg. the newest revision) but not the full history and if the central repository is down you cannot commit another revision.

In contrast, git has - at least from a technical standpoint - no central repository. So when you checkout a repository in git, you clone the complete history and you commit everything to the local repository. You can then pull and/or push commits from and/or to other repositories in order to synchronize changes and work collaboratively.

While it is often the case that you have an authoritative branch in a "central" repository (e.g. the master branch on the public GitHub repository of your project) where the desired changes get merged, this is just a common practice that works for many projects. If you have such a git repository, your "original" repository (where you initialised and added the first commit) does not have to be online all the time. On the other hand, if GitHub goes down every node could act as hub instead since it has the more or less complete history of the project.

On a side note: If you branch your code and commit to those branches, the "original" code diverges and same thing with remote repositories. GitHub and other services call copying a repository forking because of this.

I recommend the [Pro Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control) for further reading on the subject. And if you have the time you may want to watch [Linus Torvalds on git](https://youtu.be/4XpnKHJAok8) as well.